# How can I move My ResultSet to a specific record

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I´m having some troubles moving the ResultSet current record.

I´m learning JDBC and I came from Clipper and Delphi. So I used to have some kind of "reference" like a record number or a reference to a "tagged" record, so I can save this reference and move back to this position later.
While trying to do the same with JDBC and MySql, I tried to use a select / where statement to get the record I want. Thats ok. But when I try to get the line of the record,  it happens that theres always just one line in the ResultSet (I realised it could happen even before I write the code, but I had to test, cause it´s how you learn. :)).

So, to make things short. I need a way to "find" a record by some value like the primary key (with a select/where maybe) and "save" this position. So I can move the database to this same record but with a large collection of data (not just the filtered data).
I could do a while (next()) or work arround some sql codes to make my form work in a diferent way. But it´s not my goal.

So. anyone got some tips on how to do that? Thats my DAO class. I want the method "findCod" to move my ResultSet to the same record in rsConsulta.

DAO Class:

```
    package control;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.sql.rowset.FilteredRowSet;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import model.Pais;

    /**
     *
     * @author X8
     */
    public class PaisDAO extends GenericDAO<Pais> {

        private Connection conn;
        private PreparedStatement ps;
        private ResultSet rollRs;

        private final String SELECT_QUERY="select * from paises";

        public PaisDAO() {
        }

        /**
         * Cria a conexao e retorna a mesma.
         * @return
         * @throws SQLException 
         */
        @Override
        public Connection getConnection() {
            return conn;
        }

        /**
         * @param conn 
         */
        @Override
        public void startConnection(Connection conn)  {
            this.conn=conn;

        } //startConnection

        /**
         * @throws SQLException 
         */
        @Override
        public void startDataSet() throws SQLException{
            ps=conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_QUERY, 
ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rollRs=ps.executeQuery();
        }


        @Override
        public void novo(Pais p) throws SQLException{

            try {

                rollRs.moveToInsertRow(); //nova linha
                rollRs.updateInt("pais", p.getPais());
                rollRs.updateString("abreviado", p.getAbreviado());
                rollRs.updateString("descricao",p.getDescricao());
                rollRs.updateString("icone",p.getIcone());
                rollRs.insertRow(); //Salva as alteracoes.
                rollRs.moveToCurrentRow();


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
            }

        } //fim novo pais

        @Override
        public void altera(Pais p) throws SQLException{
            try {

                rollRs.updateInt("pais", p.getPais());
                rollRs.updateString("abreviado", p.getAbreviado());
                rollRs.updateString("descricao",p.getDescricao());
                rollRs.updateString("icone",p.getIcone());
                rollRs.updateRow();
                rollRs.moveToCurrentRow();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        public void filtra(String filtro) throws SQLException{
            rollRs=ps.executeQuery(SELECT_QUERY+" where "+filtro);

        }

        public String filtraPais(int ...pais) throws SQLException{
            String query="(";
            int cont=0;
            for (int p:pais){
                query+="(pais="+Integer.toString(p)+") ";
                cont++;
                if (cont<pais.length)
                    query+="or ";
            }
            query+=")";
            filtra(query);
            return query;
        }


        @Override
        public void exclui() throws SQLException{
            rollRs.deleteRow();
            rollRs.moveToCurrentRow();
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * @throws SQLException
         */
        @Override
        public int getRow() throws SQLException{
            return rollRs.getRow();
        }
        /**
         * 
         * @param row
         * @return
         * @throws SQLException 
         */
        @Override
        public int goToRow(int row) throws SQLException{
            int oldRow=getRow();
            rollRs.absolute(row);
            return oldRow;
        }
        /**
         * 
         * @throws SQLException 
         */
        @Override
        public void first() throws SQLException{
            rollRs.first();
        }
        /**
         * 
         * @throws SQLException 
         */
        @Override
        public void last() throws SQLException {
            rollRs.last();
        }

        @Override
        public void previous() throws SQLException{
            if (rollRs.isBeforeFirst()){
                rollRs.first();
            } else {
                rollRs.previous();
            }
        }
        /**
         * 
         * @throws SQLException 
         */
        @Override
        public void next() throws SQLException{
            if (rollRs.isAfterLast()){
                rollRs.last();
            } else {
                rollRs.next();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Retorna objeto no registro atual
         * @return 
         * @throws java.sql.SQLException 
         */
        @Override
        public Pais getCurrent() throws SQLException {
            Pais p=new Pais();

            p.setPais(rollRs.getInt("Pais"));
            p.setDescricao(rollRs.getString("Descricao"));
            p.setAbreviado(rollRs.getString("Abreviado"));
            p.setIcone(rollRs.getString("Icone"));
            return p;
        }

        /**
         * Fecha todas as conexoes e datasets
         * @throws SQLException 
         */    
        @Override
        public void closeAll() throws SQLException {
            try {

                if (!rollRs.isClosed())
                    rollRs.close();
                if (!ps.isClosed())
                    ps.close();
                if (!conn.isClosed())
                    conn.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new SQLException(e.getMessage());

            }

        } //fim closeAll

        public ArrayList<Pais> asArrayList() throws SQLException{
            ArrayList <Pais> aPais=new ArrayList<>();
            first();
            aPais.add(getCurrent());
            while (rollRs.next()){
                aPais.add(getCurrent());

            }

            return aPais;
        }

        public String[] getColumnNames(){
            String[] nomes={"Pais","Abrev","Descrição","Icone"};


            return nomes;
        }

        public void findCod(Pais p) throws SQLException{
            int codPais=p.getPais();
            PreparedStatement psConsulta=conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_QUERY+" 
where pais=?", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            psConsulta.setInt(1, codPais);
            ResultSet rsConsulta=psConsulta.executeQuery();


            rsConsulta.first();
            //JOptionPane just for debug 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Line 
number"+rsConsulta.getRow());
            //there we suposed to move the rollRs dataset to the same record  
of rsConsulta
            goToRow(rsConsulta.getRow());  //always go to line 1.




        }
    } //EOF
```

Thanks in Advance. I hope I made it easy to understand.

Comment: Tricks like that are - as far as I know - not commonly used in the Java world. You might want to check if MySQL supports some form of a row_id, which generally can be used to retrieve a specific row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ResultSet` will only contain the rows that were selected by the SQL Query you executed.

If the query is `SELECT * FROM paises`, then **all** rows are transferred from the database to your program.

If the query is `SELECT * FROM paises WHERE pais=?`, then only the row(s) matching the criteria is selected. You cannot then navigate the `ResultSet` to get other rows, you'll have to execute another query.

In general, you never want **all** rows (except maybe for code tables). You should query the rows you want to see.

To update a row, you have two choices:

1. Execute an `UPDATE` SQL statement.
2. Execute a `SELECT` statement for the row to be updated using an updatable `ResultSet`, set the values and call `updateRow()`.

To insert a new row, execute an `INSERT` SQL statement. You don't want to use an updatable `ResultSet` for this, because you'd have to execute a dummy `SELECT` first, and that's inefficient.

Also, you might have a look at [CachedRowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html), for working with data in a disconnected fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. @Andreas. My DAO class already have update, insert, delete and others methods. If you read it you will see it. The rollRs object is a query with all records. While the rsConsulta is a local object query select with a where clause. The point is to move the dataset with all records, or a set of records bigger than just one. To match the query that finds one especific primary key. I dont know if theres some way to work with indexes in JDBC and return the reference to de record.

Comment: @Alex Yeah, I saw those, which is why I extended my answer to say **don't**. Execute SQL `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements, don't use `moveToInsertRow()` for inserts, and your update method should start with a refresh query from the database to select the row to be updated, *or* use a straight SQL `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Andreas. But why shouldn´t I use the moveToInsertRow. I mean. Speed/ memory usage?Concurrency? Whats better about using a select statement instead? I´m reading about documentation of CachedRowSet, WebRowSet, JoinRowSet and FilterdRowSet to learn how to work with a disconnected database. So you gave me a good tip anyway.

Comment: @Alex Say you are starting fresh. You haven't looked up any rows yet, so `ResultSet` is null. You want to insert row. Execute a SQL `INSERT` statement. Done! ---- Your way, you'd have to execute a dummy `SELECT` statement in order to get an (empty) `ResultSet`, *then* do the `moveToInsertRow()`, `updateRow()`. So, select is **not** better, it's worse.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables have a primary key, then keep a copy of the pk id in your code, and when you need to retrieve or update that row again later, execute a 'select * from x where id = ?' to retrieve it, or 'update ... where id = ?'

Comment: the point is to update the current record of the database.My form have a navigator like delphi DBNavigator and a JTable that show the records of the database. So i want the user to select one record and click "Delete" then the current record is deleted, or updated. I could just use a sql delete where id=? using the getElementAt of the table. But I want to always delete the current record of the table. So I have to move the current record to match a "search" and then delete or update.

Comment: If you keep the pk id for each row shows in your table, then when the user selects a row and clicks delete, you can execute a 'delete from x where id = ?'. It seems like you're thinking you would keep the ResultSet around after you've initially retrieved it to populate the Table, but once you've done that you would normally throw the ResulSet away. Think of the ResultSet more like a db cursor which you use one time to step through rows retrieved from the db.

Comment: If what you're looking for is an in memory representation in Java of data from your database, then JPA/HIbernate or another ORM framework might be a closer match for what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you all. I´ll assume it´s not easily done in Java at the moment without using other technologies. I accepted Andreas answer as the closest possible with the resources I have now and with some good tips. Also tank you @Kevin Hooke, I´'m still adapting my idea of how to do certain things in java, as I came from Clipper and Delphi (and a little of some c++) and frameworks are to be learned in the right time.